# Funnel Visualisation not showing any drop out of the funnel

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have set up the following funnel to see where users are falling out of the funnel from when they enter the website through to when they get to the page where you can purchase the product:

[Funnel visualisation Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GW7t.png)

[image]

From the Funnel Visualisation, you can see that some data is going through the funnel. The problem is that it doesn’t show any drop out which I find extremely unlikely.

[Funnel Visualisation View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMdlM.png)

[image]

I have done a few tests where I follow the journey and drop out at certain points. The next day when the data is in I have checked but it doesn’t show any drop out.

The URLs of these pages are dynamic see examples below:

```
/parts/index/range/specification-data/eyJtb2RlbF9pZCI6ImI0ODUyNGM5LWE1MmQtNDJmOS1hZWMxLWJjNDUzYjkzYTJhNSIsIm1vZGVsX25hbWUiOiJCQUNLSE9FIExPQURFUiAxQ1gsIDIwOCJ9/

/parts/search/sections/specification-data/eyJzZWN0aW9uX2xpc3QiOiJiMzJhYmUzNi01ODcwLTRjYTctYmM3Ny01ZjJhOTNhZTY2NjUiLCJzcGVjaWZpY2F0aW9uX2lkIjoiNjhiN2Y5NzItNjU2NC00ZDcyLWFiYTEtN2I5ZmFkMzNiOGI1IiwibW9kZWxfbmFtZSI6IjFDWCJ9/

/parts/index/sections/specification-data/eyJzZXJpYWxfbm8iOiIiLCJzcGVjaWZpY2F0aW9uX2lkIjoiNjhiN2Y5NzItNjU2NC00ZDcyLWFiYTEtN2I5ZmFkMzNiOGI1IiwidHJlZW5vZGVfaWQiOiIyMDdhN2Y3OS04MzY1LTQ2NjctOGFlNC02YTQ1NzgzMDUyYzAiLCJtb2RlbF9uYW1lIjoiMUNYIiwic2VjdGlvbl9uYW1lIjoiQTAxIFNIT1ZFTFMiLCJzZWN0aW9uX2lkIjoiYjMyYWJlMzYtNTg3MC00Y2E3LWJjNzctNWYyYTkzYWU2NjY1In0%2C/

/parts/index/part/specification-data/eyJzZXJpYWxfbm8iOiIiLCJzcGVjaWZpY2F0aW9uX2lkIjoiNjhiN2Y5NzItNjU2NC00ZDcyLWFiYTEtN2I5ZmFkMzNiOGI1IiwicGFnZV9pZCI6IjBlYjM4YzFmLWZiODUtNDM2Yy04ZmRhLWVhZmNlZjExMzg2MiIsInBhZ2VfbmFtZSI6IlNIT1ZFTCBHLlAuIDAuMjkgQ1UuTSwgMTQzME1NIiwibW9kZWxfbmFtZSI6IjFDWCIsInNlY3Rpb25fbmFtZSI6IkEwMSBTSE9WRUxTIiwic2VjdGlvbl9pZCI6ImIzMmFiZTM2LTU4NzAtNGNhNy1iYzc3LTVmMmE5M2FlNjY2NSIsInRyZWVfbm9kZSI6IjIwN2E3Zjc5LTgzNjUtNDY2Ny04YWU0LTZhNDU3ODMwNTJjMCJ9/
```

Could this be causing the issue? If so I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are the funnel steps sequential? if not, it doens't make sense using a funnel.

You should create a private view with your IP filtered and, once you are only registering your own traffic, try all possible paths described in the funnel.

That will help you to determine if the problem is in the dynamic URLs, the funnel implementation or everything is all right.

Comment: Yes the steps are sequential